# Toggle changes css selectors

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying for not to change the id property of a paragraph on button click.  That first part works.  But when the button is clicked again should revert to the original styling.  New with JavaScript so any other helpful articles would be great.

Here is the css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #attention
    {
        font-size:24px;
        background-color:yellow;
        width:300px;
    }
    #normal
    {
        background-color:white;
        font-size:12px;
    }
</style>
```

JS

```
        function changeText() {
        var text = document.getElementById("textChange");
        text.innerHTML = "New Text";
        text.id = "attention";
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div>
    <p id="textChange">Some generic text here</p>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Do Something" onclick="changeText();" />
</div>
```

Comment: Add and remove the class instead of changing the ID

Comment: Yeah try not to change the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First do not change the ID of the element.
- Toggle a class instead.
- Do not use inline event attributes. Use DOM3 listeners instead.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .attention
    {
        font-size:24px;
        background-color:yellow;
        width:300px;
    }
    .normal
    {
        background-color:white;
        font-size:12px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
    <p id="textChange">Some generic text here</p>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Do Something" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('Button1');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   var div = document.getElementById('textChange');

   div.className = 'attention';
});
```

Comment: This is great and very readable it does not change the text back to its original state once the button is clicked and the new class is displayed

Comment: ahhh i got it thanks though for pointing in the right direction

Comment: @TroyBryant. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should use classes for this type of functionality. For example like this:

```
function changeText() {
    var text = document.getElementById("textChange");
    text.innerHTML = "New Text";
    text.className = text.className == "attention" ? 'normal' : 'attention';
}
```

So CSS becomes:

```
.attention {
    font-size:24px;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:300px;
}
.normal {
    background-color:white;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5yx44/